# Nodejs app on Phusion Passenger(R) crashing randomly

Tags: node.js, hosting, passenger, plesk

I'm hosting my Nodejs app with plesk obsidian and Phusion Passenger(R).
Sometimes the application just shows this error and I have to restard the whole server to fix it.

Error:

The Phusion Passenger(R) application server tried to start the web application through a Passenger-internal helper tool called the "wrapper". But Passenger was unable to execute that helper tool because it encountered an internal error.

The stdout/stderr output of the subprocess so far is:

```
[ D 2022-09-24 14:20:50.3578 575180/T1 age/Spa/SpawnEnvSetupperMain.cpp:747 ]: shellName = 'false' detected as supporting '-l': false
```

Images:

[Error Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRSrs.png)

[Problem Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPVx8.png)

If you need more information to help me with this problem feel free to ask.